# Can I exchange my character for another one of a similar level?

Tags: borderlands

I'm re-playing Borderlands and have tried playing as Mordecai, the sniper. However, I'm not really enjoying it that much (still around level 15 though, so early). I'd like to change my level 15 Mordecai to a level 15 Brick, or Lilith, as I've already played with Roland. I know it's still early in the game but I don't want to have to re-play these last few hours *again*.

Is there a way to do this, or something like it? Hacking config files is fine with me, if it works and is safe (can be undone).

Comment: for what its worth, Mordecai becomes super fun late game once you find a sniper ammo regen class mod and a few good sniper rifles like a high damage volcano and the orion.  My favorite character out of the four is Mordecai, there's nothing better than piercing an enemy's shields with your volcano, and watching the ensuing fire explosion fill up their shields from the inside.

Comment: Also, if you don't like sniping, Mordecai's Gunslinger tree is *ridiculous*.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes I don't snipe with mordecai, my semi automatic sniper rifle (Orion) can take out hoards of enemies at once with its ricocheting splitting electric rounds ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This save editor](http://blog.gib.me/2009/10/31/borderlands-save-editor-revision-10/) will let you change your class. As usual with software of this sort, you should always make a backup before hand just in case any mishaps occur.

Comment: Thanks - maybe I'll stick with the sniper for a bit (I like the ignore-shields thing, actually!) but it's good to know there's an option.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to upgrade would be to jump into a multi-player session with 3 others that are a much higher level. You won't be able to really contribute to helping move forward in a task, but you will gain beau coup experience while the rest of the group kills enemies.

By doing this you are at no risk of using a 'non-official' save editor and mucking up your data.